# Grep returns no such file or directory when using multiple flags

Tags: grep

I am a beginner of bash script. I just started to write a script where it checks the contents of b.txt can all be found in a.txt. (line by line preferably). My code is as following:

 `grep -Ffw b.txt a.txt`

As you can see, I want to do fixed string instead of REGEX, I want to check everything from the b.txt file, because there are some strings inside the b.txt and I want to check if all of them exist in a.txt. And I also want to match the whole word only of course. So these are the requirements, however when I run this command it returns me an error says: 
`grep: w: No such file or directory`

I am thinking that maybe there are some limitations of the flags in bash? Sorry I am not really familiar with the language, didn't read much about the MAN page etc. If anyone could help me to solve the puzzle it would be appreciated :) In addition, i think if possible I would like to add a `-q` to surpress the output when there is a match also, right now I didn't add it in the example since it couldn't make it through with 3 flags even. So can anyone give me some hints here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the `b.txt` has to follow the `-f` flag. So you have to write `grep -Fwf b.txt a.txt` or `grep -wFf b.txt a.txt`

Comment: Oh thanks, it works now :) didn't expect to be this simple though

Comment: do you care to give a breif explanation on why `b.txt` has to follow the ``-f` flag? :) Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hereby some explanation from the manpage:

```
OPTIONS
   Generic Program Information
   ...
      -F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, ...
      -f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, ...
      -w, --word-regexp
              Select only those lines ...
```

As you can see, the options `-F` and `-w` are indicated ending immediately (hence the comma in `-F,` and `-w,`), but the `-f` switch is followed by `FILE,` with means they belong together.

I you want to preserve the order `Ffw`, that's possible, but then you need to do something like:

```
grep -Ff b.txt -w a.txt
```

Comment: This is really great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @kvantour, the solution is simply placing the `-f` before the `b.txt` file. 
`grep -Fwf b.txt a.txt` 
Should have thought it when it says 'no such file or directory' as it was a clear indication that flags after the `-f` were treated as the path already.